# Sorting Object of Object with sort and reduce function

Tags: javascript, key, javascript-objects, reduce, insertion-order

I have an object like this

```
//input
let data={
    "51": {"name": "text51"},
    "54": {"name": "text54"},
    "61": {"name": "text61"},
    "64": {"name": "text64"},
    "71": {"name": "text71"},
    "74": {"name": "text74"},
    "81": {"name": "text81"},
    "84": {"name": "text84"}
}

/*
targeted output
{
    "51": {"name": "text51"},
    "61": {"name": "text61"},
    "71": {"name": "text71"},
    "81": {"name": "text81"},
    "54": {"name": "text54"},
    "64": {"name": "text64"},
    "74": {"name": "text74"},
    "84": {"name": "text84"}
}
*/
```

I sort it base on the digit of the keys.

```
new_key=Object.keys(data).sort((a, b)=>parseInt(a.slice(-1)) - parseInt(b.slice(-1)));
//output is ---> ['51', '61', '71', '81', '54', '64', '74', '84']
```

Now I want to rearrange the object base on the above output. (I did that)

```
result=new_key.reduce((r, k) => {
    console.log(r);
    r[k] = data[k];
    return r;
}, {});
```

When I `console.log(r)` for each iteration I got this:

[image]

My question is why when `54` key came it went to the middle of the object instead of going to the end.

Comment: It would be better to use an array than forcing object property sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object keys order was not guaranteed earlier in JS. Now it is. But here is how it is going to [be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/10140124).

What matters here is for integer like keys, the order will be **ascending**.

For string keys it is **order of insertion**, which can be tested by appending a character to the integer every time.

```js
let data={
    "51": {"name": "text51"},
    "54": {"name": "text54"},
    "61": {"name": "text61"},
    "64": {"name": "text64"},
    "71": {"name": "text71"},
    "74": {"name": "text74"},
    "81": {"name": "text81"},
    "84": {"name": "text84"}
};

let new_key=Object.keys(data).sort((a, b)=>parseInt(a.slice(-1)) - parseInt(b.slice(-1)));

let result=new_key.reduce((r, k) => {
    console.log(r);
    r['x-' + k] = data[k];
    return r;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define your own sorting of object keys, as browser (and ES specifications) tend do do their own sorting.

You can find a ton of questions and answers on StackOverflow (a couple examples: [ES5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/), [ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties))

If you really care about the order, I would suggest using an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(
  Object.entries({

    "51": {"name": "text51"},
    "54": {"name": "text54"},
    "61": {"name": "text61"},
    "64": {"name": "text64"},
    "71": {"name": "text71"},
    "74": {"name": "text74"},
    "81": {"name": "text81"},
    "84": {"name": "text84"},

  }).sort(([aKey], [bKey]) => {

    const aInt = parseInt(aKey.split('').reverse().join(''), 10);
    const bInt = parseInt(bKey.split('').reverse().join(''), 10);
    return aInt - bInt;

  }).reduce((result, [key, value]) =>

    // - key insertion prescedence/order is guaranteed since ES6/ES2015.
    //
    // - but is does not apply for pure digit based keys.
    // - insertion of the latter is handled by an ascending key order.
    //
    // ... try ...
    Object.assign(result, { [key]: value }), {}
    // ... versus ...
    // Object.assign(result, { [`_${ key }`]: value }), {}
  )
);
console.log(
  Object.entries({

    "51": {"name": "text51"},
    "54": {"name": "text54"},
    "61": {"name": "text61"},
    "64": {"name": "text64"},
    "71": {"name": "text71"},
    "74": {"name": "text74"},
    "81": {"name": "text81"},
    "84": {"name": "text84"},

  }).sort(([aKey], [bKey]) => {

    const aInt = parseInt(aKey.split('').reverse().join(''), 10);
    const bInt = parseInt(bKey.split('').reverse().join(''), 10);
    return aInt - bInt;

  }).reduce((result, [key, value]) =>

    // - key insertion prescedence/order is guaranteed since ES6/ES2015.
    //
    // - but is does not apply for pure digit based keys.
    // - insertion of the latter is handled by an ascending key order.
    //
    // ... try ...
    // Object.assign(result, { [key]: value }), {}
    // ... versus ...
    Object.assign(result, { [`_${ key }`]: value }), {}
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```